# Creating clustered and non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I was going through the topic of CLUSTERED INDEX & NON-CLUSTERED INDEX, and I gained some pretty good knowledge about how they work and their effect on performance.
The very next thought I had was, "HOW TO CREATE THESE INDEXES? and, DO THEY GET CREATED AUTOMATICALLY WHILE CREATING UNIQUE KEY or/and PRIMARY KEY?"
WHAT CASES CAN I COME ACROSS IN FUTURE, RELATED TO DEFINING/REDEFINING OF THESE INDEXES?

Please help me with that. Thanks in advance!

Also, these above questions came to my mind after reading these on MSDN pages [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15) & [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I would suggest to read help and try various examples yourself. I would say that primary key is by default clustered index, but often it is advisable to create PK as normal (unique) index and to create clustered index separately. About 'how to create' - either using SSMS wizards or by writing suitable SQL statements directly :)

Comment: You should go easy on writing in ALL CAPS - first, because it's reallly annoying and hard to read (and doesn't add anything beneficial to your post) and secondly because it's generally on the internet considering **SHOUTING** - so your post here got *pretty LOUD* already......

Answer (score 1):

You already found these two pages on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) ("MSDN" or "Microsoft Developer Network" would be the *old* name):

- Page "one": [Clustered and Nonclustered Indexes Described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described)
- Page "two": [Create Primary Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys)

Some of the answers to your questions are also available on Microsoft Docs:

- [SQL Server Index Architecture and Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide)
  This should provide you with some guidelines towards (future) scenarios where indexes are useful.
- [Create Clustered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes)
  [Create Nonclustered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes)
  [Modify an Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/modify-an-index)
  These pages can get you started on how to create and modify indexes.
- [Reorganize and rebuild](http://Resolve%20index%20fragmentation%20by%20reorganizing%20or%20rebuilding%20indexes)
  If with "redefine" you meant the maintenance that is required for indexes, then you can start on this documentation page.